# C++ sequential container initialization using iterator

Tags: c++11, iterator, containers

I'm trying to create sub containers of a container through container<\T>(InputIt First, InputIt Last). For example, I have a string s1="AreYouOK". 
The expected outputs are

```
A
Ar
Are
AreY
AreYo
AreYou
AreYouO
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string s1 = "AreYouOK";
    vector<string> v;

    for (string::const_iterator iter = s1.begin();
            iter != s1.end()-1; ++iter)
    {
        string s(s1.begin(),iter); // no matching container
        s += *iter;
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    for (vector<string>::const_iterator iter = v.begin();
            iter != v.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the commented line

```
string s(s1.begin(),iter);
```

to create a substring s of string s1 in range [s1.begin(), iter), since iter is an iterator of s1. However, I was told that there is no matching constructor for initialization.

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'string' 
(aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
string s(s1.begin(),iter);
       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

While

```
string s(s1.begin(),s1.begin+3);
```

did manage to create a substring.

Why

```
string s(s1.begin(),iter);
```

did not work?

Many thanks!

Comment: `s1.begin()` returns an `iterator`, while `iter` is a `const_iterator`. None of the constructors take an (iterator, const_iterator) pair.

Comment: You could avoid this if you used [std::accumulate](http://ideone.com/yaSA8m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look [here](https://ideone.com/OR7iPM), for example, you can see that a full error message contains

```
prog.cpp:19:33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator&)'
```

which says that it thinks your calling a constructor that takes an `iterator` and (reference to) `const_iterator`. There is no such constructor. Since `s1` is a non-const object, `s1.begin()` returns a regular iterator.

There are many ways around this. One of them is to change your loop to

```
    string::const_iterator b = s1.begin();
    for (string::const_iterator iter = b;
            iter != s1.end()-1; ++iter)
    {
        string s(b,iter);
        ...
```

Here you indeed use two const iterators (see [here](https://ideone.com/xeC925) your expected output).

---

**Edit**

Two excellent (and superior) alternatives are:

1. Use `cbegin` if you're C++11 enabled (@rici)
2. Use `accumulate`, once you get to that algorithm (@PaulMcKenzie)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just change it too `string s(s1.cbegin(),iter);`

Comment: @rici That's an excellent point, but it's not tagged as C++11, so IDK if the OP has that. Will add that as a comment, though. Thanks.